# Trying to show that $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{n^n}{n!} $ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, infinity

I have been trying to prove this using the ratio test $|\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_n}|$ , which leads me to this expression: $$\left|\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{n^n}\right|=\left|\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n\cdot(n+1)}\right|\cong as \space n\to\infty \frac{n^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}$$ While it is true that the series diverges, I am getting the wrong ratio value.

Comment: But it does not converge. It diverges, because the terms do not even have limit $0$, they are all $\ge 1$.

Comment: My Answer key says that it diverges with the ratio being equal to e

Comment: The ratio simplifies to $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}$, that is, to $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

Comment: So it's your $\cong$ that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last step is incorrect.  In fact,
$$ \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n(n+1)}
= \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n
= \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n $$
which you might recognize.

In your last step, on the bottom you replaced $n+1$ with $n$, which is okay here because their ratio is $\frac{n+1}{n} = 1+\frac1n \to 1$; but on the top you replaced $(n+1)^{n+1}$ with $n^n$, which is not okay, because their ratio doesn't tend to $1$.  Intuitively, the issue is that the exponentiation to the power $n$ makes small differences become large, and the often negligible difference between $n+1$ and $n$ becomes not negligible in such a context.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show by induction or inspection that $n^n \geq n!$. Then your terms do not converge to zero so the series necessarily diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{(n+1)(n+1)^n}{(n+1)n!}\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\rightarrow e>1$$

Comment: The last "$=$" is false. The correction to make is obvious, but mandatory.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks for your comments